# Trying to create a handler for .maff files in Linux

Tags: linux, associations, mime-types

MAFF files are simply zip files. I'm trying to create a handler for .maff in linux so that when I click on them or type xdg-open x.maff it will call my handler instead of the default which is to open the directory in nautilus. I created an application-x-maff.xml file that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="application/x-maff">
    <comment>maff type</comment>
    <magic priority="100">
        <match offset="0" type="string" value="PK\x03\x04" />
    </magic>
    <glob pattern="*.maff"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

and saved in ~/.local/share/mime/packages. Created also a ~/.local/share/applications/maffapplication.desktop that contains

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-maff
Name=Maff Handler
Exec=<my home path>/bin/linux/maffHandler
```

and executed

```
% update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/packages/
% update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

If I do

```
% gio info x.maff (filtered)
 standard::content-type: application/x-maff
 standard::fast-content-type: application/x-maff
```

and if I do

```
% gio mime application/x-maff 
Registered applications:
        maffapplication.desktop
Recommended applications:
        maffapplication.desktop
```

everything seems to be right ... but then xdg-open x.maff does not work, still calls nautilus ... worse yet, if I do

```
% xdg-mime query filetype x.maff 
 application/zip
```

I'm sure I'm missing something ... somehow I need to override this association between the .maff file that starts with the same magic as a zip file to no avail ... I tried all kinds of modifications on the xml file, with and without the magic, nothing works

By the way, if I do

```
% maffHandler x.maff
```

it works perfectly and opens the maff file in firefox, I'm willing to share the C++ code of that if anyone is interested

Answer (score 0):

Seems that TDE (Trinity Desktop) does not properly set two important environment variables

```
setenv XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP KDE
setenv KDE_SESSION_VERSION 5
```

Once they are set at .login (unfortunately had to log out and login again) xdg- scripts started working properly and recognizing the MIME types. The other problem is that TDE requires that you manually add the association on Control Center -> TDE Components -> File Associations.

After environment variables properly set for my environment and File Associations set, then it all works perfectly. Thanks